# How does one discern a calling to the vocation of religious life?

Tags: catholicism, religious-orders, vocations, calling, religious-life

Approaching this from a Catholic perspective, I'd like to ask believers how they came to know that they were called to join the religious life (as a brother or nun), as opposed to the other vocations (priesthood, marriage, single life etc). Rephrasing the same question, what should a believer look for when discerning whether they are called to the vocation of religious life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some resources:

- *[Vocation to the Religious State](http://www.saintsbooks.net/books/St.%20Alphonsus%20Maria%20de%20Liguori%20-%20Vocation%20to%20the%20Religious%20State.htm)* by St. Alphonsus de Liguori
- [*Vocations Explained: Matrimony, Virginity, the Religious State and the Priesthood*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31311) by A Vincentian Father.
- *[Vocations](http://sspxasia.com/Documents/Society_of_Saint_Pius_X/Vocations/Vocations.htm)* by Rev. William Doyle, S.J.
- [*Religious Vocation: An Unnecessary Mystery*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5891) by Fr. Richard Butler, O.P.

See also Pope Pius XII's apostolic constitution [*Sede Sapientiæ*](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/A36CYF5N/Pius%20XII%20-%201956%20-%20The%20Apostolic%20Constitution,%20Sedes%20Sapientiae.pdf) on vocations to the religious life says (part II.) that two necessary conditions must be met when discerning a vocation: that one is **called by God** and **called by the Church**.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer directly from a Catholic point of view, but the identification of a calling to the priesthood in the Anglican church probably has some similarities. I also know people who have been called to religious communities.

The key thing is that the identification of such a calling is done by the community. Thus you don't show up at a theological college (or presumably a monastry) and ask to be admitted. Instead it is done by approaching your own parish priest, who will also talk to other people who know you, and probably instruct you to do the same. At later stages a Bishop will be involve, and also a group of people who have special skills in discerning such callings.

Discernment of the calling has usually taken many years. There have been retreats and visits to religious communities, and discussion and prayer with the people in those communities, as well as other people.

Comment: I'm not qualified to say whether this corresponds to the Catholic point of view, but it strikes me as being full of wisdom. (And somewhat like the difference between 'falling in love' and an arranged marriage :))

Answer (score -3):

Why? This will be the question asked most often. "Why do you want to be a...?" And related: "What can you do as an ordained person that you cannot do as a lay person?"

The theology of 'calling' is pretty low in my Diocese (Episcopal). That is to say, it's less of a calling and more of an offering. An offering of where one is and what gifts one has and how God can make use of what you bring.

Here's this.

> The saying is trustworthy: If anyone aspires to the office of
>   overseer, he desires a noble task. Therefore an overseer must be above
>   reproach, the husband of one wife, sober-minded, self-controlled,
>   respectable, hospitable, able to teach, not a drunkard, not violent
>   but gentle, not quarrelsome, not a lover of money. He must manage his
>   own household well, with all dignity keeping his children submissive,
>   for if someone does not know how to manage his own household, how will
>   he care for God's church? ([1 Timothy 3:1-13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Timothy%203:1-13))

Comment: The call to a 'religious life' isn't the same as a call to leadership, or to ordination.

Comment: A) This question ask for a Catholic response, not an Episcopal one B) you seem to have not interpretted the 'religous life' label the way Catholics do and answered from a Protestant idea of the term. I don'n see how this answers the question that was asked.

Comment: I agree @Caleb, though the answer was still useful, mentioning at least one component that is necessary in the discernment process, thanks Stephen.

Comment: @W1M0 You're welcome. I thought the anglo-catholic tradition of the Episcopal Church might tangentially apply in some regard. We're not as Protestant as Caleb thinks.